# Android zoom in and center around custom marker in a map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google map API V2. I have disabled the map.isMyLocationEnabled() so I use my own custom icon in place of the blue dot. Since the my location layer is disabled the map doesn't zoom in around my icon. Can someone point me on how to do that?

```
GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange (Location location) {
                   LatLng loc = new LatLng (location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                   if (marker != null) {
                        marker.remove(); // remove the old marker
                    }
                    marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(loc)
                            .draggable(true)
                            .title("Not your location? wait 10 few seconds until the icon displays your real location")
                            .visible(true)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mmyicon))
                            .flat(true));   // allows it rotate with the earth and change
                                            // perspective as needed and retain it's
                                            // size
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), 15));
                //startIntentService(location);
                }
            };
            map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

Comment: Hello @The_Martian Can You Help me with This Comment i also want same functionality in my app.      "I am working on animating car location based on a real time location updates from another app. So how can I get the LatLng List when I only have the current location? Is there a way I can delay the drawing of the app to collect few updates then add all to a List object and pass it to your method and continue to repeat that until the final destination?".

Comment: I would say delay the drawing by few seconds and add the LatLng objects to a list then loop over them and draw them on the map. Google roads api had good documentation on how to cancel the noises and draw the line on the road using the same technique I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you disable myLocation layer by `map.setMyLocationEnabled(false)`, this listener become not working too.

So you should receive location by another way. 
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

After you set everything correct you can draw marker on this callback.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    ...
}
```